# Build Xcarchive with Developer certificate in Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: xcode, certificate, titanium, appcelerator, xcarchive

I am currently developing an iOS application as a subcontractor for a customer with a very specific deployment process.

For security reasons, they can not provide me production certificate, so the deployment process is the following :

1 - They provide me a developper certificate (and the matching provisioning profile) ;
2 - I build an xcarchive signed with this certificate ;
3 - they deploy the xcarchive with their production certificate.

This works fine when developing native application in Xcode, because there is no restriction for signing an archive with a developper certificate.

But with Appcelerator Studio/CLI, the only way I've found to generate an xcarchive is via the Package deployment with the Studio. But this require a production certificate, and I don't have any.

Is there another way to create this archive with a developper certificate, so I can provide it to this company I'm working with ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it is exactly what you are after. But if you run your app on a device it will generate an IPA file (in the /build/iphone/build/.... directory). Could you use that?

That is what I use to upload to installrapp for distributing tests :-)

/John